# Insert Paragraph within Equation

Tags: math-mode

How to insert a paragraph inside equation. I need to be able to break lines inside the paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
        \begin{align*}
            y =& C_1e^{(3+2i)x} + C_2e^{(3-2i)x} \\
                     & \left\downarrow\rule{0cm}{1.5cm}\right.\quad\text{Insert text here with line breaks}\\
            y =& e^{3t}\left(A_1\cos 2t + A_2\sin 2t\right)
            \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a `\parbox`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
        \begin{align*}
            y =& C_1e^{(3+2i)x} + C_2e^{(3-2i)x} \\
                     & \left\downarrow\rule{0cm}{1.5cm}\right.\quad\text{%
            \parbox{2.5cm}{Insert text here with line breaks}}\\
            y =& e^{3t}\left(A_1\cos 2t + A_2\sin 2t\right)
            \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can I make the text aligned left. Currently, with `parbox` it is stretched.

Comment: I guess I can use `flushleft`

Comment: Yes, or `\raggedright`